# Looping Div Content with JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, delay, fadeout

I'm pretty new to JQuery, I've just about grasped the concept of HTML/CSS, now I'm ready for a bit more advanced code and I've seen some pretty awesome things done in JQuery!

SO I've got this div with a class called 'contnet', multiple in one section, however I only want one to be displayed at a singular time, fading in and out from each other.

I know there are .fadeIn and .fadeOut functions, however I do not know how to loop through them on a cycle.

Thanks!

Comment: Mere trying doesn't help you in future, even though you get answers from SO.

Comment: Hi new user.Welcome to stackoverflow please check http://stackoverflow.com/tour and http://stackoverflow.com/help and http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic to know how to use stackoverflow better

Comment: Sorry guys, I have been trying, I'm just new to all this and figured that this might just be a good place to start. I'll have a look through your links to better myself in future :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just made the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x2ut3/1/) for you

If my understanding is correct, this should do the job! Although I'm just using images in my divs, you can put any content you want in there.

**HTML**

```
<div class="imgloop">
    <img src="http://hq.squidoo.com/files/2013/01/draft_lens14637921_1287867138penguin_posters.png"/>
</div>
<div class="imgloop">
    <img src="http://www.openlettersmonthly.com/likefire/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/angry-penguin.jpg"/>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.imgloop {
    width:250px;
    height:250px;
    display:none;
}
```

**JQuery**

```
(function() {

    var imgloop         = $(".imgloop");
    var imgloopIndex = -1;

    function showNextimgQuote() {
        ++imgloopIndex;
        imgloop.eq(imgloopIndex % imgloop.length)
        .fadeIn(1000)
        .delay(4000)
        .fadeOut(1000, showNextimgQuote);
    }

    showNextimgQuote();

})();


        .fadeIn(1000)
```

Set how long it takes for the new content to fade in.

```
        .delay(4000)
```

Set how long the content is visible to your viewers.

```
        .fadeOut(1000, showNextimgQuote);
```

Set how long it takes for the content to fade out.

**NOTE:** These values are in miliseconds, 1000 is equal to one second.

Comment: Thanks Tim Marshall! This works awesome!